# Wordpress - I changed my permalink structure, now images are not displaying

Tags: php, wordpress, image, permalinks

I changed my permalink structure from post number to post name. However, now all of my images are not displaying except for on the home page. All of them have `src= "./wp-content..."`. I read about a solution where I can just explicitly write `src = " http://site.."`, however, I really would like to not have to do that for a couple of reasons. Is there any way to make it work like it worked when the permalink structure was post number? Thanks.

Comment: They should not have a relative path. What about `src="/wp-content..."`

Comment: I just tried that. If I do that, they don't even display on my home page.

Comment: Give us a full url example of an image from before, and an example of a valid image url now. Are these image urls hard coded into your template file or something?

Comment: Before, something like:"./wp-content/themes/backyard-cures/images/backyard_logo.png" was working on all pages. Now, that URL is only valid on the home page. Yes, these URLs are hard coded into my template. I am also using the local avatars plugin. In my template I call get_avatar(user_id) and it produces a URL similar to   what I wrote above.